# is there any way to regenerate flutter framework

Tags: flutter

Today when I compile my project, I found the flutter framework is lost:

[image]

why would this happen? is there anyway to regenerate the flutter framework?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to re-run the app on iOS, Flutter will automatically generate the Flutter.framework for you.

Answer (score 0):

Common the Xcode will auto copy framework by self, because I delete the PhaseScript so recreate it will fix this:

```
/bin/sh "$FLUTTER_ROOT/packages/flutter_tools/bin/xcode_backend.sh" build
```

the UI like this:

[image]